# How to define default for a const rvalue reference parameter using a named variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

I have a complex class type and I want to define a default constant instance that can be copied an used as a parameter to a function. I also want to use that instance as a default parameter so the function can be called without it. The function expects a const rvalue reference.

In the following code, the disadvantage of function test1 is that the code for the definition of the default value is duplicated.

Is the function test2 valid? Will the defaultS be left in unspecified state after the first call? In that case, is there a better way to avoid code duplication?

The code prints 2 1 1 as expected when compiled with or without optimization (gcc 4.8). However, can it be relied on to work with any compiler (that supports c++11)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct S {
    // Imagine that this is a very complex class.
    int data1, data2, data3;
};

// Duplicated code for defining default parameter and the constexpr.
// This example is trivial, but remember that S is more complex in a real use case.
constexpr S defaultS = {0, 0, 1};
void test1(const S&& arg = S{0, 0, 1}) {
    std::cout << arg.data1 + arg.data2 + arg.data3 << std::endl;
}

// Default values are defined only once when defining defaultS.
// Will defaultS be unspecified after first call?
void test2(const S&& arg = std::move(defaultS)) {
    std::cout << arg.data1 + arg.data2 + arg.data3 << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // Use case for defaultS.
    // Most values are default but a few are changed.
    auto param = defaultS;
    param.data3 = 2;
    test1(std::move(param));

    test2(); // defaultS is moved from.
    test2(); // defaultS is used again here. Is it unspecified?
             // and will there therefore be undefined behaviour?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to pass a `S const&&`? It seems, you really want to use a `S const&` as you won't be able to move from a `S const&&` anyway.

Comment: I'm mostly just curious if what I'm asking is possible. I suppose that rvalue reference parameters are just for silly optimization.

Comment: rvalue references to `const` exist mostly for reasons of orthogonality -- because references to `const` exist, and not having rvalue references to `const` would cause headaches.  Barring `mutable` member data, there is nothing you can legally/politely do with an rvalue reference to `const` that you cannot do with an lvalue reference to `const`.  It may interact in interesting ways with overloading order, but you aren't doing that here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `std::move(defaultS)` deduces the argument type as `S const&` and returns a `typename std::remove_reference<S const&>::type&&`, i.e., a `S const&&` I'd think the code is OK: you won't be able to move from the `S const&&` as the object is `const`.

It doesn't make much sense to take a `S const&&` as argument, I'd think. When you want to take a `S&&` as argument you would need to create an object, e.g. using

```
void foo(S&& value = S(defaultS)) { ... }
```

Comment: Ah. I'm new to c++11 (and not professional c++ programmer anyway) and my reaction is to use std::move when I need an rvalue. I didn't feel std::move made much sense in that context but it worked. Your answer however does make sense.

Comment: @user2079303: `std::move` is just misleadingly named. A better name would (imho) be `std::movable`. However, that would still clash a bit with the decided semantics, that it can be applied to a `const` thing without producing a movable. :(

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Indeed, `std::move()` doesn't move anything which seems to be a constant source of confusion. All it really does is make its argument look like an r-value to the compiler.